# How to prevent URL encoding while using FORM and INPUT

Tags: html, forms, url, search, encoding

How can I prevent the URL I put in my forms and inputs from being encoded?

**Code (JADE):**

```
form(method="get" action="http://whateverdomain.com/blabla?")
    input(type="text" name="action=basic&searchstr" size="31" value)
```

^That spits out this:

```
"http://whateverdomain.com/blabla?action%3Dbasic%26searchstr=mySearchQuery"
```

And that doesn't work — Which is why I'm asking for help here.

**Context:**

I'm trying to make myself a custom 'New Tab' page with search boxes connected to the sites (forums, etc) I often use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `action="blabla?action=basic`, `name="searchstr"`...

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When using a form with `methot="get"`, all your form elements' names and values will be appended to the query string of the `action` URI for the request that is issued when you submit the form.

When building the query string, the browser will percent-encode the names of the form fields.

If you have any query string parameters that you want to hardcode in the request URI, either add them as hidden form fields:

```
<form action="blabla">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="basic" />
    ...
```

Or add them to the query string of the `action` URI:

```
<form action="blabla?action=basic" ...>
```